# How to get php mail to recognize From address

Tags: php, sendmail

I have a mail script with these code snippets:

```
$headers['From']        = 'Server <valid_account@mydomain.com>';
$headers['To']          = $to;
$headers['Subject']     = 'Mail Test from Server';
$headers['Reply-To']    = 'no-reply@mydomain.com';
$headers['Bcc']         = '';
$headers['Return-Path'] = 'valid_account@mydomain.com';
...
$mail_object =& Mail::factory('mail');
$mail_object->send($recipient, $headers, $body);
...
// Define SMTP Parameters
$params['host']     = 'mail.mydomain.com';
$params['port']     = '25';
$params['auth']     = 'PLAIN';
$params['username'] = 'valid_account@mydomain.com';
$params['password'] = 'abcdefgh';
```

Here are the mail headers from the incoming message:

```
Received: from nobody by vps.mydomain.com with local (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from <nobody@vps.mydomain.com>)   id 1WTE9v-0002NR-C8; Thu, 27
 Mar 2014 13:32:07 -0400
To: <myaccount@yahoo.com>
Subject: Mail Test from Server
From: Server <valid_account@mydomain.com>
Reply-To: <no-reply@mydomain.com>
Message-ID: <E1WTE9v-0002NR-C8@vps.mydomain.com>
Sender: Nobody <nobody@vps.mydomain.com>
Date: Thu, 27 Mar 2014 13:32:07 -0400
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - vps.mydomain.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [99 99] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - vps.mydomain.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: vps.mydomain.com: uid via acl_c_vhost_owner from authenticated_id: nobody from /only user confirmed/virtual account not confirmed
X-PM-Spam-Prob: : 9%
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain
Return-Path: nobody@vps.mydomain.com
```

**My Question / My Need**

How do I change my mail script to show the proper from address? s/b `Server <valid_account@mydomain.com>` and not `Nobody <nobody@vps.mydomain.com>`

Comment: Is this on windows or linux? Are you connecting to an SMTP server with SMTP-Auth, or just using `mail()`?

Comment: is `sendmail_from` defined in PHP.INI ? If not, do so. Alternatively, try `$mail_object =& Mail::factory('mail', '-f bounce@domain.com');` ref: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Linux (using `sendmail` backend to `mail()`), pass `-fvalid_account@mydomain.com` to the `Mail` object during construction like this:

```
// and any other params you'd like...
$params = array();
$params["sendmail_args"] = "-fvalid_account@mydomain.com";

$mail_object =& Mail::factory('sendmail', $params);
$mail_object->send($recipient, $headers, $body);
```

Note that the backend was changed to `sendmail`. I'd recommend setting the backend, instead of using `mail()`. See the full list here: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php

Based on your edit, here's what you need for the SMTP backend:

```
$params = array();
$params['host']     = 'mail.mydomain.com';
$params['port']     = '25';
$params['auth']     = 'PLAIN';
$params['username'] = 'valid_account@mydomain.com';
$params['password'] = 'abcdefgh';
// and any other params you'd like...

$mail_object =& Mail::factory('smtp', $params);
$mail_object->send($recipient, $headers, $body);
```

Comment: quick question for you @TajMorton. I updated my OQ. I am using SMTP auth as well. Do I send all $headers and $params? Or just $headers? Or just $params? Thanks for helping.

Comment: @H.Ferrence You'll need both. `$params` sets _how_ `Mail` sends your email, whereas `$headers` controls the headers that are included in your email. By setting the `username` parameter, the SMTP server knows which `Sender` to set, since this is one of the headers set by the MTA, not by PHP.

Comment: So if I combine $headers with $params into one array like this `$mail_object =& Mail::factory('sendmail', $combinedInto1);` then what happens with `$mail_object->send($recipient, $combinedInto1, $body);` ?

Comment: I imagine that your SMTP username and password would probably end up as headers in your email, which you really don't want. Is there a reason to combine them?

Comment: I did not see your edited answer. So does `$params["sendmail_args"] = "-fvalid_account@mydomain.com";` get added to the $params in your answer?

Comment: @H.Ferrence If you have an SMTP backend, only use the 2nd block of code. Note that the `backend` parameter in the `factory()` call is now `'smptp'`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this using php mail

```
$headers = 'From: Server <valid_account@mydomain.com>\r\n';
$headers .= 'Return-Path: Server <valid_account@mydomain.com>\r\n';
$headers .= "Reply-To: valid_account@mydomain.com\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $headers, $body, "-fvalid_account@mydomain.com");
```

Please note the 5th parameter on the mail function.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Hi use the PHP mail function,

```
$headers = 'Server <valid_account@mydomain.com>';
$to = 'test@test.com';
$message = 'My message';
$subject  = 'Mail Test from Server';

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to say -- how does that help me with my code?